# Prevent socat from stealing stdin

Tags: linux, bash, stdin, telnet, socat

I use `socat` for quick telnet banner grabbing, like this:

```
for ip in $list
do
    socat -T 1 - tcp:$ip:23 &
done
```

It loops through the list of specified IP addresses, and for each one calls `socat` which links `TCP socket` on port 23 with `stdin` (-) and disconnects after one second, while running in the background. The problem is that all of the background processes use same `stdin`, so all of them will hang. I tried `readline` option, as well suppressing `stdin` with `</dev/null`, but with no results. `netcat`, for example behaves in the same way, unless `-d` is specified to ignore the input.

The `socat` line that I specified is a part of a script that is being used for other purposes, so it would be nice if the problem could be solved without resorting to `masscan`, `nmap` or `netcat`. Thank you.

Comment: I don't really know what you're trying to achieve, but does it help if you replace `-` with a process substitution that does nothing? this: `socat -T 1 <(:) tcp:$ip:23 &`.

Comment: You specified `< /dev/null` _before_ `&`, right?

Comment: `socat` must be allowed to time out after one second. If `echo -n |` or `</dev/null` are provided from one end of the pipeline or the other, it sends nothing and quits the session immediately, sometimes before the banner is even displayed. When provided with `<(:)`, `socat` complains about /dev/fd/.. being a read-only file system.

Answer (score 0):

There has to be a better way to do this, but so far I haven't found it.

The problem with echo -n | is that when the echo is finished a sigpipe will be sent to socat.

so to get around this I did

while true; do sleep 10 ; done | socat -T 1 - tcp:$ip:23

this gives a pipe and doesn't end.